# Declaring more variables with one var keyword

Tags: javascript

Could you explain the following:

var i,j = 2;

Is the value of 2 assigned to both i and j or only to the last one, in this case, j?

Thanks.

Comment: only to the last. the comma is a separator for variable declaration. it has no assignment function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i,j = 2;
```

is equivalent to:

```
var i;
var j = 2;
```

---

**Illustrative Example:**

```js
var i,j = 2;

console.log('i is ' + i);
console.log('j is ' + j);

var ii;
var jj = 2;

console.log('ii is ' + ii);
console.log('jj is ' + jj);
```

Answer (score 0):

So i answer your question 
that

```
var i,j=2;
```

In this line of code tells that we have two variables i and j but instead of this we separated these two variables in comma and j declares a value which is 2.

and if we remove the comma between two variables its gives error because the variable have only one key.